# Why this excel string comparison return fail?

Tags: excel

Is it an Excel bug? Anyone have experienced this issue, please help?

[image: EXCEL BUG]

Comment: What is `=LEN(A5)` ? You may have non-printing characters like a line feed (e.g. CHAR(10)) or a non-breaking space (e.g. CHAR(160)) that TRIM is not clearing. Try `=TRIM(CLEAN(A5))="MANAGER"` .

Comment: @Jeeped  CLEAN only removes the BEL character per MS.   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d?CorrelationId=729433ca-941f-4d00-9507-91ec5f3dc033&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @Keng - That's exactly why I didn't post it as an answer. The [CLEAN function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/clean-function-328724f9-98cc-4a67-a50e-6bd8d33dcc61) does a horrible job of actually clearing out unwanted characters. The [LEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-6a149d3a-ba2e-4394-ad47-2eb083265a56) will at least show what the problem is. A formula like `=CODE(MID($A$5, ROW(1:1), 1))` dragged down will show the code for each character, visible or not.

Comment: did you get your source from an html page cut/paste?

Comment: I noticed that there is a line feed after the word in cell A5 just like Jeeped said. When I used =LEN(A5) it return 8 instead of 7, so the CLEAN function works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but here's what MS says about TRIM

> The TRIM function was designed to trim the 7-bit ASCII space character
>   (value 32) from text. In the Unicode character set, there is an
>   additional space character called the nonbreaking space character that
>   has a decimal value of 160. This character is commonly used in Web
>   pages as the HTML entity,  . By itself, the TRIM function does
>   not remove this nonbreaking space character.

you might try this to replace the non-breaking space (if that is your problem here).

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A5,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I would have to agree with @Jeeped. Your formula looks correct in all aspects. It must be a non-printing character. If this data is coming from some outside source (I.e. another file) then there very well could be a non-printed character. I just typed in everything you had manually and came up with this.